# change text color on some dates in material calendarview

Tags: java, android

Hello i am using a custom calendarview [this](https://github.com/prolificinteractive/material-calendarview) and i am trying to change three things in calendar

- hide and disable next button button on calendar toolbar (Next month arrow on top header)
- Add a custom text color on some specific days of months for example change text color of all Sunday to red
- make a custom selection of dates in month and also change their text color to red like [2,10,17,30]

I am new to android development so i can not understand how to use Decorator class which is there in there documentation

what i have done is installed library in my app and in my main activity created a instance of calendar but don't know to use that instance with decorator class

**MainActivity**

```
 MaterialCalendarView materialCalendar = (MaterialCalendarView)findViewById(R.id.calendarView);
```

**Decorator Class**

```
public class EventDecorator implements DayViewDecorator {

    private final int color;
    private final HashSet<CalendarDay> dates;

    public EventDecorator(int color, Collection<CalendarDay> dates) {
        this.color = color;
        this.dates = new HashSet<>(dates);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean shouldDecorate(CalendarDay day) {
        return dates.contains(day);
    }

    @Override
    public void decorate(DayViewFacade view) {
        view.addSpan(new DotSpan(5, color));
    }
}
```

Please help me with my three requirements
Thanks